# Insert metadata on song on iOS

Tags: ios4, mp3, metadata, core-audio

I'm developing an application that generates a MP3 file. I would like to insert metadata( name, artist and cover to be exact) on it. How may I do that?

Answer (score 0):

There's a C++ lib called TagLib which also works on iOS.